# read from file and add numbers

Tags: bash, addition

I have text file with entries like
123
112
3333
44
2

How to add these numbers and get the sum of these.

Comment: @Basilevs Bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example:

```
$ cat numbers.txt
123 112 3333 44 2

$ SUM=0; for i in `cat numbers.txt`; do SUM=$(($SUM + $i)); done; echo $SUM
3614
```

See also: [Bash Programming Introduction, section on arithmetic evaluation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2)

Another way would be to use `bc`, an arbitrary precision calculator language:

```
$ echo '123 112 3333 44 2' | tr ' ' '\n' | paste -sd+ | bc
3614
```

Paste usually works on lines, so we need `tr`.

Answer (score 5):

A Bash-only (no `cat`) variation on **MYYN's** answer.

```
sum=0; for i in $(<number_file); do ((sum += i)); done; echo $sum
```

Also, note the simpler arithmetic statement.

Comment: for OP's sample data, yes it works. But not when decimal numbers/floats are involved.

Answer (score 2):

just one awk command does it. It doesn't break when you have decimals to add as well.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i}END{print s}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in Awk

```
echo "123 112 3333 44 2" | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i } END {print sum}'
```

Or if it's in a file

```
cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i } END {print sum}'
```

I find Awk much easier to read/remember. Although "Dave Jarvis" solution is particular neat!